# GWT MVP with Places & Activities: how to remove the trailing hash in default place?

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to remove the trailing hash in default place?

When user navigates to default place, the browser url is like: `http://myexample.com#`, is there a way to remove the last `#`, as it may cause problem in my app(go to a page with `#` at the end will force the page scroll to top, which is not what I expect).

Also I think this behavior is not consistent: in other places other than default, the behavior is just fine.

Comment: A view is not going to scroll on its own. There must be some code in a view or in a corresponding activity that makes it scroll.

Comment: I update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I use a default place. I don't get a hash in the URL. How do you set a default place?

Comment: You need to navigate from other place to default place, the hash will appear at the end of the url.

Comment: For example, you are on: `http://example.com#myplace`, then click a link to navigate it to the default place, then the url should be: `http://example.com#`. See [www.iwordlist.com](http://www.iwordlist.com) for a live example.

Comment: As the title suggests, I use GWT's default activity/place, `placeController.goTo(new DefaultPlace())` to navigate to default place, this is what happen in a clickHandler, no Anchor widget.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Every time I call placeController.goTo(new Place()), I see a name of a place in the URL after the # character - just like you do for all your other places. Is there anything special about the DefaultPlace()?

Comment: Probably the place you are going to is not the default place, or you do not setup a default place like so: `placeHistoryHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, defaultPlace);`, by default, GWT will not show something like `#defaultPlace` when you go to default place, instead it will show `#`, that's what my question for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use standard Activities and Places pattern, with Tokenizers, you can set a space as a token to your default place. I have not tried it, but I think it would prevent the scrolling.

```
placeHistoryHandler.register(placeController, eventBus, new DefaultPlace(" "));
```